# Write a linux script that takes a directory as an argument and then prints the longest entry in that directory as an output

Tags: linux, unix

i just want to know how to do this take a directory as an argument and then prints the longest entry in that directory as an output.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Based on the language you use, you can use its native commands or call the shell commands to get a full list of the files under that directory recursively. Then you may treat each entry as a string and compare their lengths in a loop.

Comment: Start by deciding what language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f | awk '{ fils[$0]=length($0) } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc";for ( i in fils ) { largfil=i } print largfil }'
```

With find piped through to awk, first search a given directory ($1 signifying a passed argument) for files and then through awk, create an array fils indexed with the file names and with the length of the filenames as the value. In the end block, set the sort order accordingly and then loop through the array setting a variable largfil to the filename from the array. We then print largfil at the end of the loop, signifying the filename with the largest character size.